# How to find which key is in the keystore?

Tags: cryptography, keytool

If I have a lot of keys and keystore generated with keytool, how I can get information, which of given key is in the keystore?

I know how to check which certificate is in the keystore (if I try to add certificate, there is a return info if key is in the keystore), but how I can get this information for a lot of keys?

Comment: This is too little information. What kind of key store? What kind of keytool commands? Generally you know which keys are in the key store under a specific label. Otherwise you can iterate over the keys in the key store.

Comment: In task, I only have a lot of keys and keystore. And that is it. With console keytool tool and bash script eventualy, I must find which key is in the keystore. I used command 'keytool -list -keystore store.jks' but that gives me certificates in keystore only.

Comment: Did you try the `-v` command line parameter? Note that generally the private keys are part of a certificate chain. The Java key stores have always been rather PKI minded. If there is a key it would be called a "key entry".